# Which browsers and browser versions does window.openDialog support and is it in danger of being deprecated or phased out?

Tags: javascript, browser, dialog, deprecated, window.open

There is some code I am analyzing which uses `window.showModalDialog`. Don't yell at me; it's not my code. My job is to replace it. It needs to be vanilla JS, no frameworks. showModalDialog is deprecated. I replaced it with `window.open`, to support all browsers, including IE versions 7+.

I found the link below which discusses `window.openDialog`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.openDialog

I would prefer the window to behave like a dialog window. That would be great. The problem is I don't know much about `window.openDialog`. Is it standardized to HTML5 or will be? Is it in danger of being phased out? Which browser and browser versions support it?

I have no problem using `window.open`. But if I can use `window.openDialog` instead and not worry about it being deprecated or phased out, that would be preferred.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.openDialog#Specification

"DOM Level 0. Not part of any standard."

Meaning it's not officially supported anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I saw that. Does that mean it's experimental, because it could be adopted but it also could not?

Comment: it's not experimental, it's just not part of the standard. It's an extension to window.open, and browsers may implement it if they wish.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much for the clarification. I'll keep using window.open, then. Thanks again.